# Pulling records from one table (products) depending on a value in another (department)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Products table and a Departments table.
In products model:

```
has_one :department
```

In departments model:

```
belongs_to :products
```

I also have a view in my products controller that lists all departments as so:

```
<% @departments.each do |department| %>
            <div class="column_entry">
                <%= link_to image_tag(department.image_attachment), products_of_a_given_main_cat_url %>
            </div>
<% end %>
```

Those load up fine. When I click on one of the images I want products_of_a_given_main_category view to dynamically populate with products from the department whose image I clicked.

In my products controller:

```
def products_of_a_given_main_cat

  @products = Product.all
  @department = Department.where(:name == :department)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @products }
  end
end
```

and in the view:

```
<div class="the_grid_prod">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <% if product.department == @department.name %>
            <div class="column_entry">
            <%= link_to image_tag(product.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(product.id) %>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

When I click on the image for a department that I'm certain has products the page loads but there are no products. I'm certain I'm doing something very wrong but I'm not really sure what it is.

in routes file:

```
 get 'products/products_of_a_given_main_cat' => :products_of_a_given_main_cat, :as => :products_of_a_given_main_cat
```

Comment: This is an aside, I suppose, but something is off about the associations. Department belongs_to :product(s)? You have a product_id column in your departments table? This seems inverted. Don't you want `Department has_many :products` and `Product belongs_to :department`? And the products table has a department_id column?

Comment: @TomL thanks for pointing this out, I wouldn't have noticed it on my own and it did help solve the problem

Comment: No problem! I don't like to assume too much about how ppl structure their data but it looked like a bigger issue than your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
@department = Department.where(:name == :department)
```

The `:department` is a symbol, not a string, and not a variable. Basically it is a number deep down, definietly not a name. Also, this will evaluate to Departments which have a name `false`. Don't do evaluation in the where part, only a hash.

You need the `params[:department]` if you get it from the request.

```
@department = Department.where(:name => params[:department])
```

Update:

Please modify your request link:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(department.image_attachment), products_of_a_given_main_cat_url(:department => department.name) %>
```

This will introduce a new parameter to the request, and it will work for you with the condition written above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it's helped me understand a little more about how to work with tables but the page is still loading blank unfortunately. I'mm double check my records to make sure there are definitely products for the department but is there anywhere else I could be going wrong?

Comment: @SoSimple Can you please add the route for this action and the link text to your question? There is a big chance that you are using `id` instead of `department`. Try the query with `:name => params[:id]`.

Comment: the route has been added and the link text is there as well it's: <%= link_to image_tag(department.image_attachment), products_of_a_given_main_cat_url %>. The query doesn't seem to be working with id either.

Comment: Please see the updqated answer. You simple left out the parameter from the request, your action have no idea which category it should display.

Comment: Unfortunately the page is still blank. @department.name in the link was giving a NoMethodError on name so I changed it to department.name. I'll look at this again tomorrow with fresh eyes. I'm probably still doing something wrong.

Comment: My bad, please remove the `@` before `department.name`.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this problem I changed my associations as @TomL suggested in his comment. I also changed the following:

In products controller I deleted

```
@department = Department.where(:name => params[:department])
```

and changed

```
  @products = Product.all
```

to

```
 @products = Product.where(:department => params[:department])
```

The products_of_a_give_main_category_view now looks like this:

```
<div class="the_grid_prod">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="column_entry">
            <%= link_to image_tag(product.product_image.url(:normal_page_size)), products_content_url(product.id) %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Thanks to both @Matzi and @TomL for their help. It's greatly appreciated.